# How to store adjacency matrix of a graph using bitmap 2D array

Tags: c, arrays, bitmap

I want to store a adjacency matrix of a very large graph (approx. 40k nodes). But using int and char array for that I am getting segmentation fault due to memory limits.Dynamic allocation using malloc also failed here. Can anyone suggest a method to implement this using a bitmap 2D array? 
Here's my implementation so far in C :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int MAX = 50000;

void clustering(char adj[][MAX]);

int count_neighbour_edges(int temp[], int len, char adj[][MAX]);

int main()
{
   int nol = 0, i, j, k;    
   FILE *ptr_file1,*ptr_file2;

   struct community
   {
      int node;
      int clust;
   };
   struct community d;

   ptr_file1 = fopen("community.txt","r");

   if (!ptr_file1)
    return 1;

   while(fscanf(ptr_file1,"%d %d",&d.node, &d.clust)!=EOF)  //Getting total no. of nodes from here
   {
     nol++;
   }

   char adj[nol+1][nol+1];     //Getting segmentation fault here    

   struct adjacency
   {
       int node1;
       int node2;
   };
   struct adjacency a;

   ptr_file2 = fopen("Email-Enron.txt","r");

   if (!ptr_file2)
    return 1;




    while(fscanf(ptr_file2,"%d %d",&a.node1, &a.node2)!=EOF)
    {
       adj[a.node1][a.node2] = '1'; 
       adj[a.node2][a.node1] = '1'; 
    } 

    clustering(adj);
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: You might want to try to store the matrix on the heap (using malloc). You'll need about 1.6 GB which shouldn't be a problem, at least on a 64-bit system. Storing the matrix on the stack will certainly result in a stack overflow.

Comment: @nwellnhof I had already tried this. It didn't work.

Comment: how comes it's not enough? it should be ok to alloc 1.6G memory. if you work in linux, i think `brk(2)` or `sbrk(2)` should allow you to higher the limit of allocation. or, easier way, is to use `mmap(2)`. it allows you to allocate looooooots of pages of memory.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put the array in the DATA segment. You do this by declaring it outside any function and later use that memory area as a dynamically sized 2-dimensional array:

```
char buffer[MY_MAX_SIZE];

int main()
{

...

    if ((nol+1)*(nol+1) > MY_MAX_SIZE) {
        exit(1);   // Too large to fit in buffer!
    }
    char (*adj)[nol+1] = buffer;     // Use the space in buffer as a dynamic 2-dimensional array.
```

The slightly unintuitive declaration is because the size of `nol` is unknown at compile time, so I cannot declare buffer as a two-dimensional array of the size you want.

You need to decide on a value for MY_MAX_SIZE that fits the problem size and that your platform can handle, for example

```
#define MY_MAX_SIZE (40000L * 40000L)
```